# UpdateUI - Cannot Resolve Method

Tags: android, firebase

I've implemented Google Sign in into my app in order to use the user feature in Firebase. Everything works fine but my `UpdateUI(user)` method. It stays in that red error color saying that it **Cannot resolve method 'updateUI (com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser)'**. What can I do? I need this to work. Everything is working, the user can login perfectly but it is not redirected to the Main Intent because of this.

Comment: I've seen that question already. It did not help

Comment: you need to implement  updateUI Method on your own like this:
  
    private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user){
            //update ui code here
            if (user !=null){
                startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, 
                                    TargetActivity.class)
               }

        }

Comment: and that updateui code is for example, opening an intent?